# Uploading a file to box.net

Tags: c++, qt

I want to upload a file to Box.net using my application. i have done everything else what i am not able to find how to make request to the box.net for uploading
files.On developer box net has mentioned something like this for uploading files

```
curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-F filename=@FILE_NAME \
-F folder_id=PARENT_FOLDER_ID
```

I have done this much\

```
 O2Requestor * requestor = new O2Requestor(Core::sharedManager ()->getNetworkAccessManager (), mO2BoxNet, this);

    QUrl url = QUrl("https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content");

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization","462K9Ic9S*************GD");
```

I want to know that how should i append other two parameters required i.e

```
-F filename=@FILE_NAME \
-F folder_id=PARENT_FOLDER_ID
```

to the request and how should i post a request .i.e parameters required in Post function.

Comment: Where you set the `Authorization` header you miss the `Bearer` part. You are just putting your key.

Comment: For the `-F` part you need to use [QHttpMultiPart](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhttpmultipart.html) which is pretty straightforward and there are plenty of examples out there.

Comment: @alediaferia can u plz tell how should i do that actually i am a newbie to c++ and Qt

Comment: Well, can you at least link the box.net doc you are referring to? So that I can wrap up an example.

Comment: @  alediaferia        https://developers.box.com/get-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What follows is a modified version of the example you can find [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhttpmultipart.html) on the official Qt doc.

```
QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

QHttpPart textPart;
textPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"folder_id\""));
textPart.setBody("my parent folder id"); // the PARENT_FOLDER_ID

QHttpPart imagePart;
imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,        QVariant("image/jpeg")); // the actual content-type for your file
imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"filename\""));
QFile *file = new QFile("image.jpg");
file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
imagePart.setBodyDevice(file);
file->setParent(multiPart);

request.setRawHeader("Authorization","462K9Ic9S*************GD");

QNetworkReply *reply = manager.post(request, multiPart); // use your network access manager
multiPart->setParent(reply); // delete the multiPart with the reply
```

Comment: post take the arguments of following types                                             post(const QNetworkRequest &req, const QByteArray &data). it is giving a error  cannot convert parameter 2 from 'QHttpMultiPart *' to 'const QByteArray &

Comment: Please, check the docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html
QNetworkAccessManager::post also takes `const QNetworkRequest&, QHttpMultiPart*`